# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientX' of undefined

Tags: javascript, animation, dom-events

I'm working out a simple jJavascript animation and I use `clientX` to determine the the position of the animated object, but I get the error above. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is JS code:

```
(function() {
    var pos = 0;
    var timer;
    var anim = {
        time: 100,
        obj: null,
        init: function () {
            anim.obj = document.querySelector('#ball');
            anim.obj.style.left = 0 + 'px';
            anim.cord();
            console.log(document.querySelector('.coordonnee').pageX);

        },
        cord: function (e) {
            if ( parseInt(anim.obj.style.left) >= parseInt(document.body.offsetWidth - anim.obj.offsetWidth) ) {
                anim.animBack();
            } else {
                anim.obj.style.left = parseInt( anim.obj.style.left) + 1 + 'px';
                timer = setTimeout(anim.cord, 0.5);
            }
            anim.myCord(anim.obj.event);

        },
        animBack: function() {
            if ( parseInt(anim.obj.style.left) <= 0 ) {
                anim.cord()
            } else {
                anim.obj.style.left = parseInt( anim.obj.style.left) - 1 + 'px';
                timer = setTimeout(anim.animBack, 0.5);
            }
        },
        myCord: function(e) {
            var mx = e.clientX;
            var y = e.clientY;
            console.log(anim.obj.mx);
        }
    }

    anim.init();
})(window);
```

And the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JS animation</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #ball {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background: #ff45ce;
        border-radius: 50%;
        -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="ball" ></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/animation.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to pass `anim.obj.event` instead of `e` to `myCord()`?

Comment: I pass e to myCord() but I have the same problem

Comment: My bad, I thought that function is a callback to an event.

Comment: And what do you propose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried out your code here in this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YjZs3/)** .
The error that's coming up here is : `TypeError: e is undefined` in `var mx = e.clientX;`

That's because , your event is null or not defined. Redefine your logic for this purpose .

Comment: What solution you propose. I spent all my morning to find the solution but I didn't find it.

Comment: I am not sure, All the events that are present in your functions, seem to be null or undefined. So, i do not know, what else can be used here.

Comment: You know, I tried  something else that I found here and it works well, it does not have the error above. Could you check up this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/4hPhG/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the event you are passing is null

```
anim.object.event is null in this function
anim.myCord(anim.obj.event);
```